# Some application of Rouché's theorem

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f,g$ be two entire functions.
Assume that there exist $C,R>0$ such that
$$\left|f(z)-\frac{g(z)}{z}\right| \leq \frac{C}{|z|},$$
for every $z \in \mathbb{C}$ such that $|z| \geq R$.

1. How to apply Rouché's theorem to show that $f$ and $g$ have the same number of zeros outside the open disk of radius $R$ ?
2. Are the zeros of $f$ close to the ones of $g$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is wrong. Take $g(z)=z+1$ and $f(z)=1$ as well as $C=1$ and $R=\frac{1}{2}$. Then we have
$$
\left| f(z)-\frac{g(z)}{z}\right|=\frac{1}{|z|}=\frac{C}{|z|}
$$
for all $z$ with $|z|\geq \frac{1}{2}$. However, outside of the disk with radius $\frac{1}{2}$, $g$ has exactly one zero and $f$ has none.

What you can show though is this: The premises imply that $f(z)=\frac{g(z)-g(0)}{z}$. Namely, multiplying through by $|z|$ we get
$$
|zf(z)-g(z)|\leq C
$$
for all $z$ with $|z|\geq R$. The entire function $zf(z)-g(z)$ is therefore bounded and hence constant by Liouville's theorem. This gives an $a\in\mathbb{C}$ with $zf(z)=g(z)-a$ and by plugging in $z=0$ we see that we must have $a=g(0)$. Thus $zf(z)=g(z)-g(0)$, as claimed.